# userContent.css - GMail Compose Same Color as "about:blank"

Tags: firefox, gmail, colors, css

I have some code in my Firefox userContent.css that sets the background color for the `about:blank` page.  However, the `about:blank` color also seems to apply to the text area background for creating mesages in Google Mail.

How can I set the Google Mail text background in `userContent.css` so that it doesn't use the same color as `about:blank`?

Here's my CSS for the colored `about:blank`:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(about:blank)
{
    *
    {
        background-color:      #330000 !important;
    }
}
```

And here's my unsuccessful attempt at a fix (using info from [here](http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/13291/changing-the-background-color-for-the-gmail-compose-box/)):

```
@-moz-document domain("mail.google.com")
{
    .editable
    {
        background-color: white !important;
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Here is a picture of what happens from using the `about:blank` CSS:

[image]

Comment: I'm not expert in css but: **1** I think you have the url-prefix business wrong. For example, I feel an url-prefix should look like `url-prefix(about:)` and not `url-prefix(about:blank)` because the latter is now an url and not just a prefix; **2** the styles link you provided is from 2009. Many Google sites evolve very rapidly and old styles may no longer work.

Comment: Could you provide an image to illustrate what you mean re. the gmail "text background"?

Comment: @vasa1 The `about:blank` background stuff won't work without `url-prefix`.  I tried `domain` and others, but `url-prefix` was it for `about-blank`.  In general though, I think it's supposed to be `domain`, but it didn't help my problem.
Also, here's a picture demonstrating what happens: http://s10.postimg.org/wfq5j81xj/user_Content_behavior.png